# Symfony2: How can I remove parent relationship in preRemove

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a three entity:

```
class User
{
    @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Conversation", mappedBy="sender", cascade={"remove"})
    private $send_messages;
}
```

///

```
class Conversation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="send_messages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sender_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $sender;
}
```

///

```
class Message
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Conversation", mappedBy="message")
     */
    private $conversations;

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove
     */
    function onPreRemove()
    {
         // how remove parent relationship ????
    }
}
```

When I delete the User, Conversation deleted by CASCADE. Question - how to remove and Message when deleted Coversation is last relation of Message.

Comment: Hello Clement, I tried
`
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Conversation", mappedBy="message", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $conversations;
`
but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is Doctrine2 "[Orphan removal](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal)"

> If an Entity of type A contains references to privately owned Entities B then if the reference from A to B is removed the entity B should also be removed, because it is not used anymore.